# Python Issue Deleting Duplicates from a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i'm having issues with deleting all duplicates from my output. Currently using Tkinter to take in the users input... being 4 words in 4 different text boxes. The goal is to print out all the permutations of the words.

```
  def exactMatch(entries):
  for entry in entries:
  words = [entry[1].get() for entry in entries]
  perms = [p for p in permutations((words))]

  l1 = []
  for words in perms:
  #perms2 = ','.join(str(v) for v in perms)

  l1.append(perms)

  l2 = ','.join([str(l1) for word in l1])


  l3 = l2.replace("," , ' ') #Takes out the Quotations
  l4 = l3.replace("'" , ' ' ) # Takes out the commas

  sorted_list = sorted(set(l4))

   #unique_list = list(OrderedDict(zip(l4, repeat(None))))
   #for i in l4:
      # if i not in l5:
         #  l5.append(i)

  print(sorted_list)
```

The output... When trying to get the permutations from 4 words we type in is below (p.s. Just a snippet showing output/ no duplicates) The issue is that it is printing MANY duplicates and producing a large output.

```
    ( hi    w2    w4    w3 )  ( hi    w3    w2    w4 )  ( hi    w3    w4    w2 )  ( hi    w4    w2    w3 )  ( hi    w4    w3    w2 )  ( w2    hi    w3    w4 )  ( w2    hi    w4    w3 )  ( w2    w3    hi    w4 )  ( w2    w3    w4    hi )
```

Ive tried to implement the use of Sets as well as a means of removing duplicates, however the output is not what was intended. When typing in "w1,w2,w3,w4" the output is then...

```
sorted_list = sorted(set(l4)) <- set code

[' ', '(', ')', '1', '2', '3', '4', '[', ']', 'w']
[' ', '(', ')', '1', '2', '3', '4', '[', ']', 'w']
[' ', '(', ')', '1', '2', '3', '4', '[', ']', 'w']
[' ', '(', ')', '1', '2', '3', '4', '[', ']', 'w']
```

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like making things a lot more complicated than necessary, and causing an error in the process. The structure of your code is very confusing, and you appear to do the same thing multiple times.

If your input really is `in = "w1,w2,w3,w4"` like you say, we can just

1. Split on `,`: `words = in.split(',')`, which results in the list `['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']`.
2. Turn words into a `set` to remove duplicates: `words = set(words)`.
3. Get the permutations `perms = itertools.permutations(words)`.
4. Print the permutations `print(list(perms))`.

If you get a list of words back from tkinter in `entries`, as your code seems to suggest, you don't even need step 1.

Note that **permutations** care about the order of the elements. There are 4! = 24 ways of ordering four unique elements, so you should expect 24 permutations in your output. If this is more than you expected, perhaps you're thinking of the wrong combinatoric function.